# Can we cover the area with a finite number of open intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, compactness

Assume that $A\subset[a,b]$ and there exists $\epsilon>0 , \epsilon<b-a$ such that $l(A)>b-a-\epsilon$, where $l$ is the Lebesgue measure. Let $r>0$ be a real number. Does there then exist a finite number of open intervals $\{(x_i,x_i+r)_i\}_{i=1}^N$, such that $x_i \in A \forall i$, and $l[[a,b]\cap(\cup_{i=1}^N(x_i,x_i+r))]>b-a-2\epsilon$? Note: we don't require the collection of finite intervals to cover $A$, we just have the measure reqirement.

**attempt**

It seems natural that this property should hold since $l(A)>b-a-\epsilon$ and when we create open intervals we increase the measure. Since $A$ has positive Lebesgue measure it can't be countable so that complicates thing slightly. We have no gurantee that $A$ is compact, so we can not use the open covering definition of compactness directly.

An idea I had was was looking at the open covering of $[a,b]$ by $(x,x+r), x \in (a,b]$ and $[a,\epsilon/100)$. Then I would get a finite subcovering. But among the $x$ I get there might be some in $[a,b]\backslash A$. Now I should be able to choose an $x$ in A close to an $x$ not in $A$, but I am not sure how to do this.

Do you see how to prove this?, or is it not provable?